# Save T4 output to file from an imported assembly

Tags: c#, t4

I'm attempting to create a library that I can import into a text template to make my templates easier to use. The main argument of my library is the template object. While this is not best practice I haven't yet found a viable workaround. Once I have a reference to the template object inside the library, I'm then attempting to save the output of the template to another location. 
This is the code for the library.

```
namespace Templates 
{
    public class Helper
    {
        private readonly object _thisTemplate = null;
        public Helper(object input) => _thisTemplate = input;

        public void SaveToFile(string path)
        {
            var transformTextMethod = _thisTemplate.GetType().GetMethod("TransformText");
            var content = transformTextMethod.Invoke(_thisTemplate, new object[] {}).ToString();

            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter sr = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    sr.WriteLine(content);
                    sr.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the template I use to call this library

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)$(TargetFileName)" #>
<#@ output extension="\\" #>
<#
    var helper = new Templates.Helper(this);
    var outputFile = this.Host.TemplateFile.Replace(".tt",".txt");
#>
<#= DateTime.Now.ToString() #>
<# helper.SaveToFile(outputFile); #>
```

The template has `<#@ output extension="\\" #>` so that no output is produced and instead I try to save it with the `SaveToFile` method. When I try to run this with the TextTemplatingFileGenerator it crashes Visual Studio. In order to get more information, I tried to run it as TextTemplatingFilePreProcessor but that works fine.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I also took BurnsBA's suggestion and adapted the template to work with TextTransform.exe, however that also crashes

As a workaround, I've got a base template in a templates folder in my solution directory and added the method in there like this ...

```
<#+
void SaveFile(string path)
{
    var content = this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();

    using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
    {  
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter str = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            str.WriteLine(content.Trim("\n\r".ToCharArray()));
            str.Flush();
        }
    }
}
#>
```

... and then reference this base template at the top of my templates with an include directive like this ...

```
<#@ include file="$(SolutionDir)Templates\BaseTemplate.ttinclude" #>
```

I'd still like to find a viable way to save this functionality within a class if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be helpful or not, but you might try using the [TextTransform.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/generating-files-with-the-texttransform-utility?view=vs-2019) directly and see if that gives any useful error.

Comment: With TextTransform.exe you get 'Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.' then it too crashes spectacularly before providing anything useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an infinite loop...

Calling `TransformText` inside `Helper.SaveToFile` is causing the template to be evaluated which invokes `Helper.SaveToFile` which again calls `TransformText` etc, etc.

The base class implementation works because you're using the `GenerationEnvironment` property, which doesn't evaluate the template again.

Comment: According to the PreProcessor `GenerationEnvironment` is protected and you can't access it from outside the template? Isn't `TransformText()` just `return this.GenerationEnvironment.ToString();` and therefore safe to call?

Comment: Yes, `GenerationEnvironment` is protected. Calling `TransformText` 'executes' the template, populating the `GenerationEnvironment`.